# Automate backup of a single schema in PostgreSQLl on AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, database-schema, amazon-rds

**Setup** --
I have a postgresql db running on AWS RDS. We access it from an EC2 instance using pgAdmin 3.

**Current Scenario** -- 
AWS takes a daily backup of the entire RDS instance as RDS snapshots which is stored for 15 days.
I take a manual backup of one important schema (all the data in schema included) using pgAdmin and then push this backup file to s3.

**Question** --
How do I automate this backup of a single schema (including data) in postgresql and store it on S3 (any application or script). Is there a way to automate it in pgadmin just for one schema and not the entire database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a command line tool pg_dump:

```
pg_dump \
  --host=myhostname.qwertyuiop.sc-moon-1.rds.amazonaws.com \
  --username=myusername --dbname=mydbname \
  --format=custom --file=mydbname.pg_dump
```

It needs to be the same major version as the database.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution it works through the cmd prompt.
How can I schedule it on the windows server (EC2 machine) so that this runs on a specific time daily and I don't have to run it manually. I have a script which pushes this dump onto S3. So the plan is to automate both these process

Comment: I was able to automate the process by creating a batch process of pg_dump and scheduling it using task scheduler on windows.